# Android Room FTS4 how to drop triggers created automatically

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers, android-room, fts4

Can I have control over 'insert/update/delete' triggers that are created automatically by Android Room to sync data between content and virtual tables. Can I remove update triggers that I don't need?

I've created virtual table with external content using Android Room.

Content (normal) table `Person`

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
data class Person(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @PrimaryKey
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone")
    val phone: String
)
```

Virtual table `PersonFTS` for FTS with content table `Person`

```
@Entity(tableName = "person_fts")
@Fts4(contentEntity = Person::class)
data class PersonFTS(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone")
    val phone: String
)
```

Now, Android Room has created 4 triggers to keep data synced between `Person` and `PersonFTS` automatically. Here is `PersonDatabase_Impl` generated by Android:

```
public final class PersonDatabase_Impl extends PersonDatabase {
  private volatile PersonDao _personDao;

  @Override
  protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
    final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback _openCallback = new RoomOpenHelper(configuration, new RoomOpenHelper.Delegate(3) {
      @Override
      public void createAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (`name` TEXT NOT NULL, `phone` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`name`))");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person_fts` USING FTS4(`name` TEXT NOT NULL, `phone` TEXT NOT NULL, content=`person`)");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_BEFORE_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON `person` BEGIN DELETE FROM `person_fts` WHERE `docid`=OLD.`rowid`; END");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_BEFORE_DELETE BEFORE DELETE ON `person` BEGIN DELETE FROM `person_fts` WHERE `docid`=OLD.`rowid`; END");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_AFTER_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON `person` BEGIN INSERT INTO `person_fts`(`docid`, `name`, `phone`) VALUES (NEW.`rowid`, NEW.`name`, NEW.`phone`); END");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON `person` BEGIN INSERT INTO `person_fts`(`docid`, `name`, `phone`) VALUES (NEW.`rowid`, NEW.`name`, NEW.`phone`); END");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, 'd18709b6afedf9b9ff14af93e6c8157e')");
      } 
....
}
```

I want to avoid updating data in `virtual table` if `content table` got any updates, so I need to remove triggers with names `room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_BEFORE_UPDATE` and `room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_AFTER_UPDATE`. Triggers for INSERT and DELETE operations are needed only.

Does Android Room provide such possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a CallBack and **DROP**ing the triggers in the `onCreate` and `onOpen` methods ensuring that you use `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` (so a non-existant trigger doesn't result in a failure)  e.g.

```
public static Callback cb = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_BEFORE_UPDATE");
        db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_AFTER_UPDATE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_BEFORE_UPDATE");
        db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_person_fts_AFTER_UPDATE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
    }
};
```

In your **PersonDatabase** you would include `.addCallback(cb)` in the databaseBuilder.

You could even use the following that requires no hard coding:-

```
public static Callback cb = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        getAndDeleteFTSTriggers(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        getAndDeleteFTSTriggers(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
    }

    public void getAndDeleteFTSTriggers(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor csr = db.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type  = 'trigger' AND instr(sql,'room_fts') > 0 AND instr(sql,'_UPDATE') > 0");
        int sqlidx = csr.getColumnIndex("sql");
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            db.execSQL(csr.getString(sqlidx).replace("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS","DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS"));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
};
```

- **note** the above **HAS NOT been tested** on an actual database with FTS. However, it has been tested on a database without FTS (in which case the Cursor will be empty). As such you should obviously test the above.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT, with this queries I could successfully DROP not needed update triggers from `sqlite_master`. But, now if I do update on any row of `Person` it still automatically update same row in virtual table `PersonFTS`, even though I don't have UPDATE triggers anymore in `sqlite_master`. Then, I've DROPed INSERT and DELETE triggers as well, but any insertion and deletion row in `Person` table automatically reflected in virtual table `PersonFTS` with zero triggers that could sync data between content and virtual table. I'm confused a little bit with this behaviour of Sqlite FTS feature :)

Comment: @devger just wondering if https://sqlite.org/fts3.html#the_content_option_ is the issue. i.e. Room creates using content=`person`, (no columns), whilst examples at link all specify columns. Also could be underlying code that room generates. I've only ever dabbled with FTS so I'm not very conversant with it.